# ExtJS Dashboard Panel Fit Panel Vertically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm creating an application that has a layout based on the ExtJS5 [Portal Demo](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/portal/index.html). I need to have a panel in the [Dashboard](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard) that will fit **vertically**, not just horizontally to fill the entire space of the column. At this time this just needs to occur for one of the panels, not all as most will have a fixed height and the user of course has the ability to resize vertically because the Dashboard panel uses anchor layout.

This panel will contain a map and I need to display as much of the map as possible. If the column contains multiple panels and the user drags one to a second column I would like for the map panel to resize and fill any empty vertical space in its column. The inverse is true, if someone drags a panel to the same column as the map panel will need to decrease but still fit to as much vertical space as possible.

I believe using a [vbox](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) layout on the panel is what I need but I've tried this on the dashboard panel with no luck. Has anyone else run into this, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what about using a fit layout?

Comment: adding fit layout to my component that is inside the Dashboard panel seems to have no affect other than the horizontal fit. thanks for the suggestion I'll continue to try fit some more.

Comment: I actually seem to be having the same issue. I used javascript as a workaround :/ let me know if you would like to see the code.

Comment: yes please, I would be interested to see your code you've used as a work around.

Comment: check out [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109793/gridpanel-auto-height-inside-tabpanel), i posted everything I did.. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the align config on vbox - it might do what you want if you use one of the stretch options.

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-align